# What is the relationship between surface gravity and maximum animal size?

Tags: science-based, biology

It is clear that an organism can only grow so large before the systems required to keep it alive need to become impossibly efficient. Circulatory systems, respiratory systems, nervous systems, etc. have to constantly fight against gravity, atmospheric conditions and resistance.

I'm interested in gravity more. I read an unsourced statement somewhere that on Earth, an animal cannot grow to more than the size of the Pentagon due to the gravity (weight). Are there any plausible models or rough scales representing the relationship between gravity and *land animal* size? Are they linear? Logarithmic? It don't require perfection, I just need something more concrete than the square-cube law.

(Assume that atmospheric pressure and composition remain fairly constant.)

Comment: Relationship is complicated. Depends on a lot of other factors, like if it is a land or water animal, atmosphere, pressure (and these two depend on gravity) and so on. Do you have any restrains? Like, for example, if you want your animal be land or oceanic one, in what atmosphere it lives, and probably more? I'm afraid answer that takes every possibility into account could get too long for Q&A format.

Comment: How concrete do you want this relationship to be? A fairly rough relationship on the effects of gravity on animal size could probably be made by comparing the largest land critters with the largest ocean critters (who are able to compensate for gravity through buoyancy and thus grow larger).

Comment: I apologize for doing this to you, but I need to VTC as [primarily opinion-based](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6436#6437).  We have only one datapoint: Earth.  We have no idea how any other gravity will actually affect animal evolution (and we barely understand how evolution, including physical development, works here).  Answers to this question can never be anything other than a guess because there's only the one perspective to work with.  If you're writing a story, create what you want.  If you're asking out of curiosity, well....

Comment: One more thing: keep in mind that this site's focus is the development of your fictional world, meaning its rules and their consistent application.  The site really isn't meant to be a place where general hypothication is pursued.  Your world's rules can be anything you want and we'll help you develop consistent use.  Therefore, I could be wrong with my vote.  Are you developing a world?  If so, don't fall into the trap that all things about the world must be 100% science based because those answers are often unavailable.  Science fiction is expected to include fiction.

Comment: @NightKing Just a thought, but if you go to https://biology.stackexchange.com/ and figure out how to phrase the question so they like it, I'm sure they'd be pleased to help.

Comment: Note: Size is also related to oxygen content of the atmosphere https://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2011/08/110808-ancient-insects-bugs-giants-oxygen-animals-science/ - Also of course the Blue Whale is pretty big although not even nearly Pentagon-sized.

Comment: @JBH I don't think it is opinion based. Biomechanics is objective. It may be unanswerable due to other reasons.

Comment: @Mołot I agree this isn't opinion-based, but I'm not convinced it's about worldbuilding. It's more a question of understanding the real world, but with no apparent connection to the development of a fictional world.

Comment: @Frostfyre I didn't vote "leave open". I just disagree with JBH about Primarily Opinion Based reason.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "size". Mass? Volume? Height? It matters, because height is the real limiting factor here. If you have a creature that is extremely wide and low to the ground (think of a flat ground-hugging sheet of flesh that moves on millions of tiny feet), there's no real limit (at least in terms of its ability to tolerate high gravity) to how wide it could get.

Comment: @Mołot, just because there's one aspect of the question that can be addressed in a non-POB manner doesn't make the question non-POB.  Humanity's view of biomechanics is 100% from the perspective of this world.  I do not believe it is justifiably enough to present a non-POB answer without at least a second datapoint, which we don't have.  In other words, humanity's understanding of biomechanics is not godlike.

Comment: @Mołot, I'll give you an example, who's to say that on a world with heavier gravity evolution wouldn't favor the development of bone and flesh such that it has a higher weight-bearing capacity?  That results in a planet with animals the same size as here.  It's also a complete guess no matter how you relate it to terrestrial biomechanics.

Comment: @JBH the fact that you don't have enough data, or even the fact that enough data does not exist, does not make it opinion based. If there is no relationship, it is an answer, not a proof of question being opinion based.

Comment: @Mołot, bearing in mind that I completely subscribe to [this perspective of what primarily opinion-based](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6436#6437) means... How can the OP judge the best answer when nobody can be demonstrably wrong?

Comment: I'd recommend reading J.B.S. Haldane's "On Being The Right Size" for a nice write-up on how size is affected by gravity and atmospheric conditions. It's a well known, seminal work on the effects of the square-cube law on biomechanics. https://archive.org/details/OnBeingTheRightSize-J.B.S.Haldane